# Can't read swagger's doc in UI (Rails project, localhost)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, swagger-ui

When I coming to http://localhost:3000/api/swagger, I see in doc's address field http://api.webcrm.dev:3000/doc, and, as result, message `Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.` instead of my api's endpoints etc.

I trying to find proper address to use it in localhost.

in **console**:

```
Settings.api
=> {"url_options"=>{"host"=>"api.webcrm.dev", "port"=>3000, "version"=>"/v1/"},
 "swagger"=>{"discovery_url"=>{"host"=>"api.webcrm.dev", "port"=>3000, "path"=>"/doc"}}}
```

in **application.yml**:

```
api:
  url_options:
    host: api.webcrm.dev
    port: 3000
    version: /v1/
  swagger:
    discovery_url:
      host: api.webcrm.dev
      port: 3000
      path: /doc
```

in **config/initializers.010_swagger.rb**:

```
GrapeSwaggerRails.options.url     = Settings.api.swagger.discovery_url.path
GrapeSwaggerRails.options.app_url = "http://#{Settings.api.swagger.discovery_url.host}#{ ':' + Settings.api.swagger.discovery_url.port.to_s if Settings.api.swagger.discovery_url.port.present? }"
```

in **routes.rb**:

```
mount API => '/api' if ENV['ASSETS_PRECOMPILE'].blank?
  mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine => '/api/swagger'
  get '/api', to: redirect('/api/swagger')
```

But in logs output I see:

```
2020-02-19 12:11:07 +0700: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
2020-02-19 12:11:07 +0700: ENV: {"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.errors"=>#<IO:<STDERR>>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"puma 3.7.0 Snowy Sagebrush", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2"}
---
```

How can I find proper docs address and why it is not inputs automatically? Thank you so much for help!

P.S.: 

`Rails 4.2.11.1
ruby 2.3.8p459`

Answer (score 0):

Found proper address:
http://localhost:3000/api/swagger_doc
it looks like we should to make something with configs